# Inefficient javascript loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, canvas, for-loop

The images gathered into the array are layered on top of each other to complete the final picture. The issue is that once the images have loaded the loop seems to continue running because it is near impossible to scroll or have any other animation take place.

```
function map(id){
var img_elem = document.getElementById("img_elem");
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var name = <?php echo json_encode($sorted_array);?>;
var elements=<?php echo $filecount?>;
var image= [];
for(i=0;i<elements;i++){
image[i]= new Image();
image[i].src = "images/"+name[i];
image[i].setAttribute("class","container");
image[i].setAttribute("style","position:absolute");
ctx.drawImage(image[i],1,1);
alert(image[i].src);
}
}
```

Comment: And did you check the value of elements ?

Comment: _"the loop seems to continue running"_ - it either does or it doesn't. Does your alert get hit? Is the function being called multiple times? What happens if you add a console log inside your loop?

Comment: Why are you creating photos[i] as an Array instead of a simple string ?

Comment: Check what `$filecount` results in. Why not just use `name.length`?

Comment: When you ask JavaScript questions, you really should show the JavaScript result and not the php code.

Comment: I haven't found much or any real documentation on creating img elements via string. If you could give me some sort of source i'd love to look it over, dystroy. And all the elements are only being called once according to the console, Chris.

Answer (score 1):

One reason this is likely to be slow is that you're repeatedly appending elements to the DOM, which often causes the browser to redraw the page.

You can avoid a lot of it by grouping your changes and doing a single addition, something like this:

```
var buffer = [];
for(i=0;i<elements;i++){
    buffer.push("<img ",
        "src='images/",name[i],"' ",
        "class='container' ",
        "style='position:absolute' ",
        "id='",name[i],"'/>");
}
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = buffer.join(""):
```

Comment: This didn't exactly fix my issue but it solved a completely different one. So thank you!